# Clone a http request and forward it to different server on localhost

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Servlet which I call from an ajax function. What I want to do is to forward the same request (header, cookie, etc.) to a different url on localhost. I have to call a hidden php api (not public available by apache2) which I want to call with the original php session (cookie and headers).

I am sure there is a simple way to do this but I have not found something easier than making a HttpURLConnection and fill in all the data by foot. Is this really the only option?

Comment: If you just pass on the literal request, why use the servlet at all?

Comment: I don't understand your needs. Why not use `mod_proxy` (possibly with `mod_rewrite`) on your client facing Apache HTTP server? By the way [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) library supports proxy based rewrites. And maybe there is something in [Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/) as well.

Comment: because the url should not be public -> it is an API, this would be a security issue. But I need from my php app something in my java app and therefore I need to access the php session inside off the unpublic php api url.

Comment: I can understand security concerns, but what is the added value of your servlet in that use case ? Until you say that, I will think that Apache `mod_proxy` is the right tool (it **is** used for security concerns).

Comment: the servlet is doing java stuff I can not do in php. all the logic is happening in the servlet but I need some additional user data from the php app. and therefore the php app needs to know the session data (which is what my servlet revceives).